# textarea unexplained spacing

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have just noticed some wired spacing below a textarea, it is different in every browser. Can someone explain why it is there?

```css
span,
textarea {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<span>test</span>
```

[image: here is an image of it]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

`vertical-align:bottom`

This is because

> The baseline of some replaced elements, like `<textarea>`, is not specified by the HTML specification, meaning that their behavior with this keyword may change from one browser to the other.
>
> <sup>[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)</sup>

```css
span,
textarea {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<span>test</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing with `textarea` in HTML is that the text is aligned right next to the bottom margin. If you wish to have it any other way, read about the `vertical-align` attribute in CSS.

You can use:

```css
span,
textarea {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<span>test</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this style to textarea

```
vertical-align: top
```

Comment: there is no link

Comment: I meant to make a comment about adding a bit of a description to your answer. Normally you'll want to explain why this bit of code would fix the issue or answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:` top to `textarea`.

The reason for the gap is that textarea is an inline (or inline-block) element, and the gap is the space reserved for [descenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) in text.

```css
span,
textarea {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
textarea{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<span>test</span>
```